# How to use a variable from one snapshot listener in another snapshot listener

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know how I could use a variable from one snapshot listener in another snapshot listener, I am verily new to using snapshot listeners and I got stuck here. I would like to get the scores index point 0's uid so I can use it in the other snapshot listener.

I have tried returning the scores but that just gives me errors

```
const [scoreCards, setscoreCards] = useState([]); // all the users info is stored

useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
    const scorecardCollectionRef = collection(db,"competitions/" + id + "/scorecard");
    const competitionCollectionRef =  query(collection(db, "competitions"), where('id', "==",id));
    const usersCollectionRef = collection(db, "users");

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(usersCollectionRef, (snapshot) => {
      let allusers = {};

      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        allusers[doc.id] = doc.data();
      });

      onSnapshot(
        query(scorecardCollectionRef, orderBy("finalscore", "asc")),
        (snapshot) => {
          let scores = [];

          snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            scores.push({
              ...allusers[doc.data().uid],
              ...doc.data(),
            });
          });


          console.log(scores[0].uid)
///want to use scores[0].uid


          setscoreCards(scores);
        }
      );



      onSnapshot(
        query(competitionCollectionRef),
        (snapshot) => {
          snapshot.forEach((doc) =>{
            //     
      
            let comp ={
                ...doc.data(),
                id: doc.id
            }
      
            setComps(comp);
        //console.log(comp)
      
            if(today > (comp?.date.seconds*1000)+60480000){
              if(comp?.closed == 'open'){
                updatecompetitionUsersCount(id, {closed:"closed"})
              //here I want to call the above scores[0].uid
              
              }
          }

        })
        }
      );



    });

    return () => {
      //do something when screen is unfocused
      //usefull cleanup function
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [])
);
```

Comment: You will need to nest the second snapshot listener into the first one, so that is has access to the data that was loaded.

Comment: Okay thank you, is there any documentation on how to do that, because I am pretty new to this so I don't know exactly how?

Comment: You'd just move the code for the second `onSnapshot(....)` into the first one, for example right under the call to `setscoreCards(scores);`.